# One pixel vary in Firefox and chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried a lot to resolve it but couldn't solve, there is one pixel vary in chrome and firefox

[image: Chrome]
[image]

```
.lside,.rside{
 position: absolute;
 top:22.8rem;
 width: 60px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 }

.lside{
 background: url(../img/sideL.png) no-repeat;
 height: 120px;
 left: -20px;
 }

.rside{
 background: url(../img/sideR.png) no-repeat;
 height: 120px;
 right: -60px;
 }
```

One pixel vary in Firefox and chrome

Comment: is this a task to find the pixel? ;)  I think you should at least point out what exactly is not pixel perfect. after staring at the picture for a bit I guess you mean the left part in the bottom image that's shifted 1px up, right?

Comment: yes, if i increases in chrome img get down to 1px and firefox is equal to button, is there any solution to fix this.  I'm using bootstrap

Comment: what do you mean with `increases`? do you mean when you zoom in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web pages will always render differently in different browsers. So the position may differ in different browsers. I don't know any solution to fix it. I can't comment to your post because i don't have much reputation. That's why I post this as an answer. You can try firefox css hack to solve this but i'm not sure that it solves your problem.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 

  }
```

Put your code inside this snippet and try or try css reset and check you included this in yur html file

```
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">
```

Comment: Hooray, you are awesome it solved my problem thank you so much